# How to remove encircle element using javascript without target id or class?

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove encircle element using javascript without target id or class????
Like that

```
<div>
  Choice 1 <span>close X</span>
</div>
```

I hope that when someone click the "close X" word, it will delete Choice 1 and close X

I try to

```
    <div>
          Choice 1 <span onclick="remove(this)">close X</span>
    </div>
    <script>
    function remove(val) {
      //val.remove();   Just remove the "close X" word
      //val.previousElementSibling.remove();   //Not work
      //$(this).prev().remove();   using Jquery //Still Not work
    }
    </script>
```

Anyidea How to do it?? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `event.target.parentElement.remove()`

```js
function remove(event) {
  event.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
  Choice 1 <span onclick="remove(event)">close X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method on the "Close X" element to capture clicks then iterate over the child nodes of the parent `<div>` element then remove any text nodes found.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("element");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

close.addEventListener("click", () => {
  [...el.childNodes].forEach(child => child.nodeType === 3 && child.remove());
  console.log("Other functions after removing all text can be run here.");
});
```

```html
<div id="element">
  Choice 1 <span id="close">close X</span>
</div>
```

You can actually shorten it a bit by using some [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
const el = document.getElementById("element");
const close = document.getElementById("close");

close.addEventListener("click", () => ([...el.childNodes].forEach(child => child.nodeType === 3 && child.remove()), console.log("Other functions after removing all text can be run here.")));
```

```html
<div id="element">
  Choice 1 <span id="close">close X</span>
</div>
```